# Java Spring JDBC Oracle Stored Procedure returns null

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spring's Stored Procedure - results coming back from procedure always empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154386/springs-stored-procedure-results-coming-back-from-procedure-always-empty)

I have the following code and although I know the call should result in contents I always get back an empty resultset can anyone suggest why?

```
ParameterizedRowMapper<ExamPaper> mapper = new ParameterizedRowMapper<ExamPaper>() {

  public ExamPaper mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {


    logger.info("in the row mapper with"+rs.toString());
    logger.info("in the row mapper with x no of rows " +rowNum);

    ExamPaper examPaper = new ExamPaper();
    examPaper.setCampus(rs.getString("campus"));
    examPaper.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
    examPaper.setPaper(rs.getString("paper"));
    examPaper.setCode(rs.getString("code"));
    examPaper.year.add(rs.getString("year"));
    examPaper.semester.add(rs.getString("semester"));
    return examPaper;
  }
};

Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("ic_search_string","fluid");
params.put("ic_location_flag", "unmc");
logger.info("calling stored procedure");
OracleStoredProcedure storedProcedure = new OracleStoredProcedure(getDataSource(),"pkg_exam_papers.p_get_exam_papers",logger, mapper);

Map results = storedProcedure.execute(params);
logger.info(results.size());
```

---

```
public class OracleStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure 
{
  private Log logger;
  public OracleStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource,String storedProcedureName, Log logger,ParameterizedRowMapper mapper)
  {
    super();
    this.logger = logger;

    setDataSource(dataSource);
    setFunction(false);
    setSql(storedProcedureName)

    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ic_search_string", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ic_location_flag", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("orc_results", OracleTypes.CURSOR, mapper));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("on_errcode", OracleTypes.INTEGER));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("oc_errmess", OracleTypes.CHAR));

    compile();

  }

  public Map execute(Map parameters)
  {
    Map out = new HashMap();

    try 
    {
      out = super.execute(parameters);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException)
    {
      logger.error("Exception when executing stored procedure: " + nullPointerException.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
      logger.error("Exception when executing stored procedure: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    return out;
  }
}
```

Comment: A little formatting of your code would really help readability. There is a lot of white space to scroll through.

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like?  The header of it, anyway.

Comment: Apologies for code formatting - in a rush to leave the office and wanted to post the question - editing now

Comment: will post stored proc header as soon as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your questioned is answered by another similar one from a year ago: [Spring's Stored Procedure - results coming back from procedure always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154386/springs-stored-procedure-results-coming-back-from-procedure-always-empty)

Comment: The other post lead to to provide the rowmapper as an inner class this seemed to be the answer thanks gigatron

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it looks ok. Have you tried running the stored proc in sqlDeveloper with the same parameters against the same database to make sure it actually returns results?

Comment: Yes it returns results in sqldeveloper equivalent (I use db visualiser)