# How to call a stored procedure with ref cursor as an output parameter using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I have a stored procedure which has body like :-

`PROCEDURE PROC_NAME(param1 in varchar2,param2 in varchar2,results_cursor OUT CURSOR_TYPE);`

Each row of result is equivalent to an instance of a certain user defined class.

How can I call this in Spring. I went through lot of google and stackoverflow but could not find an apt answer.

Can anyone please provide me a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with JdbcTemplate but I've done it using plain JDBC. I can post some code if you can use JDBC.

Comment: @dsp_user: I cannot use JDBC in my code.

Comment: Well, JDBCTemplate already uses it internally but it's really up to you.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something I put together based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154386/springs-stored-procedure-results-coming-back-from-procedure-always-empty) and [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure):

```
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

public class SampleStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    public SampleStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource, "PROC_NAME");
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("param1", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("param2", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("results_cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new SomeRowMapper()));
        compile();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> execute(String param1, String param2) {
        Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();
        inParams.put("param1", param1);
        inParams.put("param2", param2);
        Map output = execute(inParams);
        return output;
    }
}
```

If your stored procedure is in another schema or in a package, you'll need to adjust the stored procedure name in the above.  Also, you'll need to specify a row mapper to use in place of `SomeRowMapper`.

To call it:

```
    DataSource dataSource = ... ; // get this from somewhere
    SampleStoredProcedure sp = new SampleStoredProcedure(dataSource);
    Map<String, Object> result = sp.execute("some string", "some other string");
    // Do something with 'result': in particular, result.get("results_cursor")
    // will be the list of objects returned
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a `SimpleJdbcCall`:

```
    DataSource dataSource = ... ; // get this from somewhere
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
    Map<String, Object> result =
        jdbcCall.withProcedureName("PROC_NAME")
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter("param1", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("param2", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlOutParameter("results_cursor", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new SomeRowMapper()))
            .execute("some string", "some other string");
```

If the stored procedure is in a package, you'll need to add a line

```
            .withCatalogName("PACKAGE_NAME")
```

to the setup of `jdbcCall`.  Similarly, if it's in a different schema, you'll need to add

```
            .withSchemaName("SCHEMA_NAME")
```

Comment: can you share sample implmentation of SomeRowMapper also

Answer (score 2):

Please have look a look once.
List userData;

```
    SimpleJdbcCall  executor = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                                .withProcedureName("SP_CL_USERPKS_FOLDER").withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                                .declareParameters(
                                    new SqlParameter("INparam1", Types.INTEGER),
                                    new SqlParameter("INparam2", Types.VARCHAR),
                                    new SqlOutParameter("OUTParam1", OracleTypes.CURSOR),
                                    new SqlOutParameter("OUTParam2", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    executor.compile();
    SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("INparam1", loginPk)
            .addValue("INparam2", email);

    Map map = executor.execute(param);
    userData = (List<Map>) map.get("OUTParam1");
    String msg = (String) map.get("OUTParam2");
```