# SimpleJdbcCall exception: Required input parameter is missing

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I need to use withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess(); method in SimpleJdbcCall to avoid unnecessary calls for meta date and in order to use it, I need to declare parameters. One of the parameter is OUT SYS_REFCURSOR. What type it should be when declaring it in Java?

I tried to declare it as Types.REF_CURSOR, but then I get an error: Required input parameter 'o_warning_cur' is missing

Procedure call:

```
 getStatusCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName("loan")
    .withCatalogName("b_loan")
    .withProcedureName("can_sign")
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

 getSigningStatusCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("i_contract", Types.VARCHAR));
 getSigningStatusCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("is_contract_in_paper", Types.VARCHAR));
 getSigningStatusCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter("o_warning_cur", Types.REF_CURSOR));
```

DataBase procedure:

```
PROCEDURE can_sign(i_contract IN laen.leping.leping%TYPE,
                            is_contract_in_paper IN varchar2,
                            o_warning_cur        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
```

InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required input parameter 'o_warning_cur' is missing

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045032/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-ref-cursor-as-an-output-parameter-using-spri

Answer (score 0):

For declaring output ref cursor parameter, you can call method

```
public SimpleJdbcCall returningResultSet(String parameterName, RowMapper<?> rowMapper);
```

available on SimpleJdbcCall object. In this example, it would look like this:

```
getStatusCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
        .withSchemaName("loan")
        .withCatalogName("b_loan")
        .withProcedureName("can_sign")
        .returningResultSet("o_warning_cur", rowMapper());
        .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
[...]

RowMapper<ResultDTO> rowMapper() {
    return (rs, rowNum) -> new ResultDTO(rs.getString("X"), rs.getString("Y"));
}
```

You can also try to declare it in similar way as you tried but instead of creating SqlParameter object, you create SqlOutParameter. In this example:

```
getSigningStatusCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlOutParameter("o_warning_cur", Types.REF_CURSOR));
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer. Just code is sometimes hard to interpret, for the one asking the question

Comment: Sure. I've added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You need `SqlOutParameter` with `o_warning_cur`

```
   .declareParameters(
                                new SqlParameter("i_contract", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlParameter("is_contract_in_paper",Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("o_warning_cur", Types.REF_CURSOR)
                        )
   .returningResultSet("o_warning_cur", rowMapper())
```